# How do I Count the of number of divs using jsoup?

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

How do I count the number of divs using jsoup?

What I need to be able to do is count all the "news_main" divs...

```
         <h1>Notice to Mariners</h1>
         <form name="filter-form" id="filter-form" action="/notice-to-mariners/"       enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <div style="display: none"><input type="hidden" name="filter-form" value="1"></div>
    <div style="display:none; width:0px; height:0px;"><p><label class="indent" for="filter-form-leave_blank">If you are human leave this blank:</label><input id="filter-form-leave_blank" class="" type="text" name="filter-form-leave_blank" value=""></p></div><div id="filter"><select class="" name="filter" id="filter-form-filter">
    <option value="form_error">View notices in force</option>
    <option value="1">View notices not in force</option>
    <option value="2">View all notices</option>
    </select><button type="submit">Filter</button></div><!-- / filter --></form>
        <div class="news_main">
        <div class="news_main">
        <div class="news_main">
        <div class="news_main">
        <div class="news_main">
```

etc..etc

I have tried various methods but all seem to return 0?

Code:

```
 docNtm = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mhpa.co.uk/notice-to-mariners/").timeout(600000).get();
                           Elements ntmAmount = docNtm.select("div.news_main div"); 

                            System.out.println("size:  " + ntmAmount.size());
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT:

I can now retrieve the all divs like this:

```
 10-18 22:41:36.365: I/System.out(14624): size:  0
 10-18 22:41:36.365: I/System.out(14624): size:  0
 10-18 22:41:36.365: I/System.out(14624): size:  0
 10-18 22:41:36.365: I/System.out(14624): size:  0
 10-18 22:41:36.365: I/System.out(14624): size:  0
 10-18 22:41:36.365: I/System.out(14624): size:  0
  .....etc
```

what is the best way to count them?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Element.getElementsByTag("div");` with `Element.hasClass("news_main");`

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://www.mhpa.co.uk/notice-to-mariners/");

Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements divs = content.getElementsByTag("div");
int ntmAmount = 0;
for (Element div : divs) {
  if (div.hasClass("news_main"))
    ntmAmount++;
}
```

or `Element.getElementsByClass("news_main");`

```
...
Elements ntmDivs = content.getElementsByClass("news_main");
int ntmAmount = ntmDivs.size();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I'm getting a nullpointer exception? with your first example and I had already tried the second which still returns 0.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to help you when you're not including your error logs or even the entire HTML document you're parsing... please include them in your question.

Comment: hi, I have solved the nullpointer, thanks allot for your help your solution has worked...can you advise of the best way to count them and get the total, please see my edit. thanks again

Comment: Great! I see that you've included your error log, but I don't see how you're calling `Elements.size()`. Is it with one of the methods that I've provided or is it the original method used in your question?

Comment: hi, yeh what I'm doing there is just system.outing all the ntmAmounts(news_main) divs, so what I mean is that I am now getting all of the divs on that webpage, where as I need the total...thanks

Comment: Okay, what method are you using to obtain the divs? `Element.getElementsByClass("news_main")`, etc?

Comment: Sorry for delay, yes it is your method that I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Elements ntmAmount = docNtm.select("div.news_main div");
```

with this:

```
Elements ntmAmount = docNtm.select("div.news_main");
```

Comment: hi, yes I have tried that previously, unfortunately it still returns 0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a direct method, but a for loop should work...

```
int count = 0;
for (Element n : ntmAmount) {
    count++;
}
```

That's assuming ntmAmount is a reference to all of the `<div>` elements you want... which, as someone else pointed out, it's not.

Instead you want `Elements ntmAmount = docNtm.select("div.news_main")`

Comment: Hi, tried this and still its not counting all the divs called .. news_main. ? thanks